# Is this XHTML document valid for parsing with the iPhone

Tags: iphone, xml, parsing, xhtml

I would be grateful if someone could clarify if this document is valid for xhtml parsing using the iphone SDK using xpaths:

```
<!DOCTYPE html
    PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en">
<head>
    <title>East Lancs Radio - Now Playing</title>
    <META HTTP-EQUIV="REFRESH" CONTENT="45">
    <meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-cache"> 
    <meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache"> 
    <meta http-equiv="Expires" CONTENT="0">
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css"/>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="player-currently-playing">
    Currently Playing

    <div class="player-track">
        Lush
    </div>

    <div class="player-artist">
        Ladykillers
    </div>
</div>

    <div id="player-playing-next">
    Playing Next

    <div class="player-track">
        Javine
    </div>

    <div class="player-artist">
        Surrender (Your...
    </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

I'm trying to extract the currently playing player-track 'lush' and player-artist 'ladykillers' through using xpath. If I do an xpath search for: //@class and then print the result to screen, I get player-track, player-artist.. etc outputted?

Am I missing something fairly obvious here?

Thanks

Dan

Comment: What library are you using for XPath? Are you setting the namespace mappings in there?

Comment: You can validate it on `http://validator.w3.org/`. For xpath it should be a valid XML, nothing more. I'm not sure how the "xpath library of iphone" works though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your XPath result is giving you what you're asking for which is the values of the class attributes.

To get the currently playing player-track use:

```
//*[@id = 'player-currently-playing']/*[@class = 'player-track']/text()
```

and to get the currently playing player-artist use:

```
//*[@id = 'player-currently-playing']/*[@class = 'player-artist']/text()
```

Comment: Thankyou! This is exactly what I've been after! Works a treat x

Answer (score 2):

The [W3C Markup Validation Service](http://validator.w3.org/) comes up with 9 errors in this document.

So, this is not a valid XHTML document, for iPhone usage or otherwise.

Comment: I was originally using the NSXMLParser but couldn't get that to work how I wanted.. and then switched to using libxml2. I can parse through the document using libxml2 but I'm having trouble reading the attributes correctly due to the errors in the document.. back to the drawing board.